# how to set jquery ajax post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, backend

I'm a beginner at JavaScript so I need help.

I have some HTML with a button:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
            <div class="profile-photo">
                <object data="image/avatar.svg" type=""></object>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="text-area-comments">
                <textarea name="post-comments" maxlength="255" id="post-comments" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message" required=""></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11 offset-lg-1">
            <div class="button-post-comment text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-warning text-muted" type="submit" id="send">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And now I need to post a new comment from the page to the back-end.

```
$("#send").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '***',
    type: 'POST',
    dateType: 'json',
    data: {
      "text": $("#post-comments").val(), "parent": null,
      _method: 'POST'
    },
    success: function(data){

    }
  });
});
```

Who can help me - what must I be doing next?

Comment: Kinda hard to tell you 100% the correct code since we don't know your backend parameters

Comment: And you want to have this part `$("#send").click(function() { // Ajax call here });` like this, not other way round.

Comment: Params:
content - text
parent - ID of parent comment or NULL
@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: i'm edit my question code what u like sad @Adriani6

Comment: In that case it would be something like `data: { "text": $("#post-comments").val(), "parent": null }`. There's no space on your HTML for the ID of the parent comment so I don't know where you take this value from. Setting the data items is fairly basic. There are some examples at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (near the bottom) which show you the format already.

Comment: @ADyson This value i can take from my last ajax request for getting JSON data from this back-end.

Comment: Ok good. So does my suggestion help solve your problem then?

Comment: @ADyson yeah - but i's so stupid i think( because i don't know how to write a function to post my data(text) from (text-area) to json on back-end((

Comment: You can put all data to send inside a <form> and send all in json format using serialize() .... example:

var frm = $('#form_id');
type: frm.attr('method'),
url: frm.attr('action'),
data: frm.serialize(),

Comment: @ADyson can i contact with you in some messenger?

Comment: "i don't know how to write a function to post my data(text) from (text-area)" - I already showed you how to do it, in my comment before. Is there a problem with it? P.S. You are not sending your data as JSON, and there's likely no need to either (unless the backend requires it?)

Comment: No there is no private messenger on StackOverflow. The whole point of the site is that the questions and answers are public for future readers to learn from.

Comment: @adyson 422 (Unprocessable Entity) -  that's message i see in console, when i'm trying to post text from text-area

Comment: ` _method: 'POST'` this seems odd.. it should be `'_method': 'POST'`

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze It's unclear why that's there, but AFAIK it's not invalid.

Comment: @ADyson if it's a param the server needs then it could actually be.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze sorry I changed my comment, realised I was wrong. But why on earth the server would need it I don't know, it can already tell whether it's receiving a POST or GET or whatever without being given a variable.

Comment: @ADyson yeah it makes no sense

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич do you really need `_method: 'POST'`? What's the purpose of that? Your server will already know it is receiving a POST request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179527/discussion-between-kevinspaceyiskeysersoze-and-adyson).

Comment: Anyway please show us the backend code which receives this request. We don't know what it is actually expecting.

Comment: i'm edit code JS with Url to api @ADyson

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич that doesn't give us access to the code, or even the spec, though.

Comment: That's all what i have - check new link to photo with all data what i have @ADyson

Comment: your trying to post to a get that will not work if you want to update a comment use the id of this comment

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze no OP is trying to post to the one labelled "new comment"

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич you just aren't reading the spec correctly. The field name should be "content", not "text". It shows it quite clearly at http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/extmnzw5/10/ . Pay more attention to the field names in future. I knew we needed to see the spec.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Да, SO гораздо жестче, чем ruSo. Так что пока побудьте на ruSO, там воды поспокойней, потом, понимая все, идите сюда.

Comment: @VerNick да это старый вопрос, я тогда только начинал пользоваться данным community - поэтому не знал правил, да и вообще мало чего знал, сейчас я понимаю и правила, и как лучше формулировать вопросы и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the spec for your API at http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/, you are setting the wrong field name. Your field should be called "content", not "text". You need to pay closer attention to the specifics. It says:

> Request: POST `http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/pages/YOUR E-MAIL/comments`
>
> Params:
>
> - content - text
> - parent - ID of parent comment or NULL

```
$("#send").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/pages/you@yourdomain.com/comments',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
      "content": $("#post-comments").val(),
      "parent": null
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
});
```

Notice `"content": $("#post-comments").val()` in particular. You also had a typo `dateType` which I've corrected to `dataType`.

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/extmnzw5/10/

P.S. I realise the text/comments mixup is partly my fault - I suggested using `text` as an example. The wording of the spec you gave in the comments was not formatted well and was therefore unclear. It would have been better to give us access the full spec from the beginning.

Comment: Thank You so much - you r really help me... i Must more studding for This  -  i have one question more - can u edit URL to **** for others people ?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич I can, so it's less obvious, but anyone can look at the history of the question (by clicking on the "edited x minutes ago" link) or the answer and see it. Unfortunately from the moment you published the URL in the question it was permanently public. The only way around it is to delete the entire question. Even then, users with high enough reputation can see deleted questions, although they don't show up in searches etc any more